# how to read json elements

Tags: json, flutter, foreach

i have a json to read and add the items into a list but foreach method not working :(
my json is:

```
{"elements":[{"id":9,"payVal":222,"payDate":"2021-08-10T19:30:00Z","isCharity":true,"imgFileUrls":[],"firstName":"Admin","lastName":"Admin","nationalCode":"2280113732","applicationUserId":"5701c92c-a1ee-4721-91de-08d932684d82"}],"totalElements":6}
```

my code(responseBody includes the json) :

```
final responseBody = json.decode(response.body)['elements'];
  responseBody.forEach((item) {
    _transactions.add(TransactionModel.fromJson(item));
  });
```

Comment: Try List.from(json.decode(response.body)['elements']);

Comment: can you share your `TransactionModel`

Comment: You should use mapping instead of for each method.

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question. A [repro] would fit well here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping is the better way to achieve it.

**The TransactionModel Class**

```
class TransactionModel {
  final int id;
  final int payVal;
  final String payDate;
  final bool isCharity;
  final List imgFileUrls;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String nationalCode;
  final String applicationUserId;
  
TransactionModel(
  this.id, this.payVal, this.payDate, this.isCharity,this.imgFileUrls, 
  this.firstName, this.lastName, this.nationalCode,
  this.applicationUserId);

  static TransactionModel fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
      return TransactionModel(
          map['id'],
          map['payVal'],
          map['payDate'],
          map['isCharity'],
          map['imgFileUrls'],
          map['firstName'],
          map['lastName'],
          map['nationalCode'],
          map['applicationUserId']);
 }
}
```

Now let's make a method to read JSON and return list of transaction model objects.

```
List<TransactionModel> readJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data['elements'])
      .map((e) => TransactionModel.fromMap(e))
      .toList();
}
```